# SpringMvc tiles not showing the header and footer

Tags: java, css, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

In my project I have **tiles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC  
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN"  
        "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">

<tiles-definitions>

    <definition name="base.definition"  template="/WEB-INF/layoutStyle/layout.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/layoutStyle/header.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/layoutStyle/footer.jsp" />


    </definition>

    <definition name="home" extends="base.definition">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="home" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/home.jsp" />

    </definition>


</tiles-definitions>
```

the **spring-servlet.xml** is:--

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-4.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.1.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.patra.news" />

<mvc:default-servlet-handler />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <bean id="tilesViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver"
        p:order="0" p:viewClass="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView"
        p:viewNames=".*" />

    <bean id="jstlViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
        p:order="1" p:viewClass="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"
        p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <!-- Tiles Configuration -->

<bean id="tilesConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**web.xml** is:--

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
                             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">

  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
     <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>

 </init-param>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
      </servlet>


  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**layout.jsp**  is:--

```
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="tiles" uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" %>



<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title><tiles:insertAttribute name="title" ignore="true" /></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="resources/css/screen.css" />" type="text/css" media="screen, projection"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="resources/css/print.css" />" type="text/css" media="print"></link>


    <%-- 
    <link href="<c:url value="/resources/main.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/jquery.1.10.2.min.js" />"></script> --%>

<style>
body{ margin-top:20px; margin-bottom:20px; background-color:#DFDFDF;}
</style>

</head>


<body>
        <div class="container" style="border: #C1C1C1 solid 1px; border-radius:10px;">
        <!-- Header -->
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
                <!-- Body Page -->
        <div class="span-19 last">
            <tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
        </div>
        <!-- Footer Page -->
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**header.jsp** is:--

```
<div class="span-24">
    <img src="resources/images/logo.png" 
        width="90" style="padding-top:10px;" />
</div>
```

**footer.jsp** is:--

```
<hr />
<div class="span-1 prepend-3">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="span-16 last">
    <p>
        <b>TechZoo - A Zoo of Technology</b> 
        ( All rights Reserved)
    </p>
</div>
```

**home.jsp** is:--

```
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"%>
<%@taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>

<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/header_style.css" type="text/css" media="print"></link> -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/navstyle.css" type="text/css" media="print"></link> 


 <style>
table.reference tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
tbody {
  display: table-row-group;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-color: inherit;
}
table.reference tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
tr {
  display: table-row;
  vertical-align: inherit;
  border-color: inherit;
}
</style>
<div style="margin: 10px;">
    <h4>List of Persons</h4>
    <table style="width: 600px" class="reference">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Sr. No.</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**index.jsp** is:--

```
<jsp:forward page="home.htm"/>
```

But When I run the project it is only showing the body..not adding the header and footer..I cant understand Where I am putting the wrong code..pls suggest me..

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with tiles 2.2 but I can suggest you to use version 3 instead

**POM**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
  <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.5</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
    <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
    <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

**tiles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
       "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN"
       "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">
```

**spring-servlet.xml**

```
<bean id="tilesViewResolver" 
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver"
</bean>
<bean id="tilesConfigurer"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
      <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
        </list>
      </property>
</bean>
```

Please **delete** the other resolver

```
<bean id="jstlViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
        p:order="1" p:viewClass="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"
        p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />
```

Comment: Thank you for response.I have tried what you have suggested..But if I change "tiles-servlet" version 2.2.2 to 3.0.5 then it is showing error and I have edited "tilesViewResolver" ..again it is showing error..

Comment: you need to add the jar to your project using maven or automatically

Comment: Yes sir..I I tried it..I have updated my pom then executed..But error was showing

Comment: you have to delete the other jar tiles 2.2

Comment: please make sure paths to each file are right. I have edited <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>

Comment: Yes sir..i know..I checked that..I have deleted the pom files and then tried what you have suggested..But nothing getting

Comment: I got it sir..Actually I had a problem of structure of files..thanks for giving suggestions..